# Tabular not showing ajax data

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I cannot get 'Tabular' to display the table with data. Have tested it on Chrome and Edge.

main.js

```
let jsonURL = './readAllUsers.php';

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxURL: jsonURL,
    ajaxResponse: (url, params, response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;
    }
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Table</title>
    <link href="/node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example-table"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.js"></script>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

readAllUsers.php returns json data ... if I examine console log output from the 'ajaxResponse' above I see test data:

```
Array(6)
0: {id: "1", firstName: "Lou", lastName: "Pieters", email: "lou@gm.com", phone: "0123456789", …}
1: {id: "2", firstName: "John", lastName: "Snow", email: "john@gm.com", phone: "0129871234", …}
2: {id: "3", firstName: "Buck", lastName: "Rogers", email: "buck@gm.com", phone: "0129986677", …}
3: {id: "4", firstName: "Tom", lastName: "Tom", email: "tom@gm.com", phone: "0129986767", …}
4: {id: "5", firstName: "Dick", lastName: "Richards", email: "dick@gm.com", phone: "0129983344", …}
5: {id: "6", firstName: "Harry", lastName: "Potter", email: "harry@gm.com", phone: "012999900", …}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: What happens when you define the different configuration properties like in the example on the homepage?

Comment: Hello Trace - it add 'pagination' buttons but still no data.

Comment: Did you define the columns? I sort of guess that they keys you define in the columns property configuration needs to correspond with the array object keys.

Comment: I thought it will create the columns dynamically from the json data? But I tried this as well ... all I get is the table with the column names .... pagination buttons and still no data.

Comment: What happens when you remove the `ajaxResponse` callback? May be useful for you to debug the unbundled source code.

Answer (score 1):

OK - there is one property that I added and it now works (without specifying the columns). I added "autoColumns: true". It is now displaying data and field names as headers. Thanks Trace for all your efforts.
(I actually thought 'autoColumns' would be 'true' by default).